# Collapsible view not working with viewpager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have a layout which contains a Horizontal `recyclerView` at top and a  `viewPager`.

ViewPager has a `recyclerView` in its each tab.

I want to collapse top `horizontal recycler view` when user scrolls the layout.

This is my code, and it does not collapses the horizontal view when user scroll the `recyclerview.`

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_appbarlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <!--  app:contentScrim : The Toolbar color when the
          collapsing toolbar is collapsed. -->


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:contentScrim="#000000"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <!-- app:layout_collapseMode : parallax means an animation effect,
             pin means fixed. -->


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvMatchup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


<!--- BOTTOM ITEMS -->


<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_appbarlayout"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />
```

Although if i use another `recyclerView` instead of `ViewPager`, it works fine, and collapses the top view.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This one will help you:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/maincontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_appbarlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <!--  app:contentScrim : The Toolbar color when the
          collapsing toolbar is collapsed. -->


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:contentScrim="#000000"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <!-- app:layout_collapseMode : parallax means an animation effect,
             pin means fixed. -->


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvMatchup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_appbarlayout"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />


<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<!--- BOTTOM ITEMS -->
```